# Could the "pizza guy" sue now had he not received the pizza?

Tags: legal

Let's pretend the guy that spent 10k BTC on a pizza in 2010 did not receive his pizza back in the day (basically got scammed). He shrugged it off as it was only ~20$.

He forgets about it, and notice now that a single bitcoin is valued at around 60k!

Would he be able to sue now 11 years later to get his 10k BTC back, or could he only hope to get back 20$ ?

Answer (score 2):

No, he wouldn't be able to sue.

- Basically the [Statute of limitations](https://www.justice.gov/archives/jm/criminal-resource-manual-968-defenses-statute-limitations#:%7E:text=The%20statute%20of%20limitations%20for,%C2%A7%203293) for scam is 5 years, after this delay the claim can be dropped in court.
- Even if he still went for it, he would only be entitled to the USD value of the transaction at that moment. It would be unreasonable to ask for a refund 10000x the price that was paid, see [I paid in bitcoin, now I'm owed a refund. Can I demand it in bitcoin too?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32489/i-paid-in-bitcoin-now-im-owed-a-refund-can-i-demand-it-in-bitcoin-too)